# I cannot format "November 9, 2000" date in EXCEL to "09.11.2000"

Tags: excel, excel-dates

So I have this data - November 9, 2000 in Excel (the column type is Date).
After hours of trying I cannot format it to something like 09.11.2000.
I've tried:

1. Column to text transformation
2. Format cells

Please help

Comment: What locale is your machine in? Per default, when formatting a cell, excel only displays date formats used in the default locale. Select for instance "German" as a locale for that cell, then it will let you select your desired format ...

Comment: Or you can always do a "userdefined" format and use `DD.MM.YYYY` as a formatstring, if you have the english version of excel. If you are in any other language consult the docs, which placeholders are appropriate in your language ...

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the cell is correctly identified as Date, right-click on the cells and select `Format Cells`, then click on `Custom` category which you can pass in `dd.mm.yyyy` as the value to display the value in the format as you have requested.

Comment: Did not help :(

Comment: @user2620644  since this doesn't work for your data, your "Dates" arn't actually dates, they are strings that only look like dates. You'll need to fix that (convert them to actual dates) for any formatting to work

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your date is currently in text format. Setting the column type to 'Date' won't affect the display of text, even if it looks like a date.

Unfortunately, Excel can't directly interpret "November 9, 2000" as a date.

Three steps are needed:

1. Convert the text date into a format which Excel can interpret as a date, such as "9 November 2000".
2. Apply Excel's `VALUE()` function to convert the text date to a real date (which means a number in Excel).
3. Apply date formatting to display the date in your desired format.

To achieve steps #1 and #2 in one go, you could apply the following formula (replace each instance of `A1` with the cell containing your text date):

`=VALUE(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1, {" ",","}), 2) & " " & INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1, {" ",","}), 1) & " " & INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1, {" ",","}), 4))`

To explain how this works:

1. `TEXTSPLIT(A1, {" ", ","})` splits the input date into an array of four elements, splitting on every space and comma. The four elements are `November`, `9`, a blank element and `2000`.
2. `INDEX(..., n)` selects the nth element of an array. We ask for elements 2, 1 and 4, in that order (i.e. `9`, `November` and `2000`).
3. We then join with spaces to give the text string `9 November 2000`.
4. Excel's `VALUE()` function then converts this text to a real date (i.e. the Excel number 36839).

Finally, to display the date as required (step #3 above), select the cell and apply custom formatting of `dd.mm.yyyy`.

(Note that if you are using locale settings other than English, some of the above steps may not work.)

This approach will work for any dates in the same format as "November 9, 2000". If you have dates in the same column in a different format, you might need to apply additional logic.